# Why result differ when I use " instead of ' in SQL injection attack?

Tags: python, sql

I am doing a course in which they used  `'); delete from posts; --` to show a famous sql injection attack but when I used `"` instead of `'` i.e. `"); delete from posts; --` it didn't worked.

The python code I used to talk to database:

```
import psycopg2

DBNAME = "forum"

def get_posts():
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=DBNAME)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("select content,time from posts order by time desc")
    return c.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    
    
def add_post(content):
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=DBNAME);
    c = conn.cursor();
    c.execute("insert into posts values('%s')"%content);
    conn.commit();
    conn.close();
```

Also when I omitted `;` i.e. `') delete from posts; --` I got an error.
Can please someone explain both of these problem to me?

Comment: `'` closes `'`, `"` closes `"`

Comment: Which DB are you using? If you omit `;` the resulting string is not valid SQL. Consider printing out the SQL being executed and inspect it. Please check what you have posted is the actual code being run: In `execute("insert into posts values('%s')"%content);` the `%content` doesn’t look right.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the SQL flavors that I know of, single- and double-quotes have two totally different syntactic meanings:

- Single quotes (`'`) are used in order to define a string literal
- Double quotes (`"`) are used in order to write an *identifier*

Therefore, it comes as no surprise that trying to inject one instead of another will have a different effect.

Example

```
SELECT "col"  -- Identifier
FROM "tab"    -- Identifier
WHERE "col2"  /* Identifier */ = 'str' /* String literal */
```

I think that in MySQL the apostrophe (`) can be used for identifiers, but it doesn't change the fact that each quote has its own meaning and use.